# "Access of undefined property" Errors AS3 FlashPunk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am completely new to Flash and am trying to learn FlashPunk for ActionScript3 in FlashDevelop.
I have been using this tutorial (http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-flashpunk-the-basics--active-9638) and am on Step 10: Collisions.

It has said to add some code to the World.as class, however when I do so I get the error, "Error: Access of undefined property _gameEntity". This happens with _box as well.

I am guessing this is something to do with variables being defined privately, therefore World.as not being able to access them.

```
    override public function update():void 
    {
        // update the entities
        var e:Entity = _updateFirst;
        while (e)
        {
            if (e.active)
            {
                if (e._tween) e.updateTweens();
                e.update();
            }
            if (e._graphic && e._graphic.active) e._graphic.update();
            e = e._updateNext;
        }
        //collisions
        super.update();

        var entityArray:Array = [];

        getType("GameEntity", entityArray);

        for each (var entity:Entity in entityArray)
        {
            entity.x = entity.x > 550 ? 550 : entity.x;
            entity.y = entity.y > 400 ? 400 : entity.y;
        }   

        if (_gameEntity.collideWith(_box, _gameEntity.x, _gameEntity.y))
        {
            trace("Collision!");
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the private var _gameEntity is defined within the GameWorld.as file *after* the GameWorld class declaration and *before* the GameWorld and update functions.

```
public class GameWorld extends World 
{
    private var _gameEntity:GameEntity;  <---------IT GOES HERE

    public function GameWorld() 
    {
        // blah blah
    }

    override public function update():void
    {
        // blah blah
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's what I have got, my _gameEntity and _box are both defined at that point before the functions and after the world extension: public class GameWorld extends World
 {
  private var _gameEntity:GameEntity;
  
  private var _box:Box;
  
  public function GameWorld()
  {
   _gameEntity = new GameEntity();
   _box = new Box();
   
   add(_gameEntity);
   add(_box);
   
   _box.x = 200;
   _box.y = 150;
   
   addGraphic(new Image(Image), 0, 50, 50);
  }

Comment: I'm at a loss. I can't download flashpunk because the official website is broken (never a good sign). Try commenting out lines of code you think might be causing the problem until the error disappears, then you'll have a better idea of where to look for mistakes. I'd start with the pieces of code added in Step 10. Sorry I can't be more help.